# In wireless communication, what is "channel length"?

Tags: digital-communications

In wireless communication, I am confused about what people are referring to when they use the term 'channel length.' Can someone explain the term or provide me a definition?

Comment: Can you provide an instance where you saw the term?

Answer (score 1):

We model channels typically as something with a memory. A typical model for such a channel is the *tapped delay-line model*.

In all the models that understand a channel to have memory, the *length* is simply the difference between the earliest effect and the latest effect of the channel.

In the tapped delay-line model, the term is effectively identical to *delay spread*, plus – depending on which book you read – the delay of the earliest impulse response.

I think when you read up on the tapped delay-line model, this will become pretty self-evident.